# Formula + Flow Assistance

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I have a field on the contact object called "sign up date" and a checkbox field on the contact object as well. I want to create a flow that triggers the creation of a case if two weeks pass the sign up date and the checkbox field has not been marked. I would imagine I would need to create an autolaunched flow since there is no record update that will be triggering the flow. Can someone help me with what a formula for this might look like? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with a formula field and an autolaunched Flow. Because formula fields are evaluated only on read, there is no trigger event that can cause automation to run when their values "change".

Instead, you will need to build a Flow that uses [scheduled tasks](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/record-triggered-flows/add-a-scheduled-task-to-your-flow) to execute automation on a schedule defined relative to the Contact's Sign Up Date, if and only if the checkbox field is not selected. I've linked the relevant Trailhead module to get started with scheduled tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me perfectly!